# Does the delete[] operator work with dynamically allocated memory returned through a pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm wondering how the delete[] operators works with pointers *returned* by a function, rather then having the dynamic allocation in the same scope as the delete statement.  Let's say I have a trivial function like this:

```
int *getArray()
{
    int *returnVal = new int[3];
    returnVal[0] = returnVal[1] = returnVal[2] = 0;
    return returnVal;
}
```

Now, when I need to use that array in my code, I would do the following:

```
int *vals = getArray();
// use values...
delete[] vals;
```

However, I'm wondering, how does the C++ compiler know how big the memory block that was allocated was (and thus how many memory elements to delete from `vals`)?  Is this a valid technique, or would I have to delete each array value individually (like in the code below)?

```
int *vals = getArray();
// use values...
delete vals + 2;
delete vals + 1;
delete vals;
```

Comment: That's an implementation detail. Which compiler are you interested in?

Comment: @VJo I'm using both VC++ 2008 and gcc, but I didn't know this was implementation dependent - thanks for that info.  I'm more interested in the proper way to do this that is consistent with C++ standards, but to be honest, I'm equally interested in *how* the compiler keeps track of all of this.

Comment: To the secondary question, absolutely do not ever do `delete vals + 2; delete vals + 1; delete vals;`. You must `delete` only the exact objects returned by `new`, and `delete[]` only the exact arrays returned by `new[]` (or in both cases a null pointer is OK). You can't `delete` one part of something allocated by `new[]`, array allocation just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only `delete[]` things obtained via `new[]`. In your code that's the value returned by `getArray()`. Deleting anything else is illegal.

> However, I'm wondering, how does the C++ compiler know how big the
>   memory block that was allocated was.

Each implementation stores the allocated size (and the type I think) in some way.

- One common idea is to store the bookkeeping information (or an index
  of some sort) right before the actual allocated memory.
- Another idea is to use the actual pointer as the key to a data structure that holds the required information

Of course this is overly simply explained (it's more like an explanation for C ). In C++ there is the added detail of destructors and whatnot.

Comment: "the key to a list" -- 'list' here in a very general sense, rather than the usual computer sense of a specific data structure.

Comment: @Steve Jessop I really have no idea what that data structure could be. A tree maybe ?

Comment: As in the C++-FAQ quoted by the.malkolm, an associative container is basically what we're after. So pretty much a tree or hashtable, maybe a skip list or something equally fancy.

Comment: Oh, or I suppose that if most allocations are small, and let's say 16 bytes is the smallest block the allocator ever creates, then you could have a big bitmap of 1 bit per 16 bytes of memory (less than 1% overhead), with value "0" if the block allocated with that address has size 16, and "1" otherwise. Then in the common case it's a single lookup in that table to find the size, and for all the other cases, you look it up in a tree/hash/whatever to get the exact size, or you store the size in the block in the more usual way.

Comment: @Steve Jessop Thanks a lot for your comments. As usual I am the one learning the most from these questions :-)

Comment: In that case I should warn that these skip lists and bitmaps are flights of fancy as to something that *might* give decent allocator performance, not things I've seen done! I have definitely seen a tree of all allocated blocks, though. It was used to enable a form of garbage collection where a pointer into the middle of a block could be identified (by finding its lower_bound in the tree and observing that the desired pointer is inside the block described at that tree node) and marked. Before anyone uses the idea commercially do a patent search, there was at least an application on it.

Answer (score 3):

It's completely OK to delete memory out of the new[] scope. Read more [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.14) and here is the quote in case you are lazy to check the link.

> [16.14] After p = new Fred[n], how does the compiler know there are n objects to be destructed during delete[] p?
>
> Short answer: Magic.
>
> Long answer: The run-time system stores the number of objects, n,
>   somewhere where it can be retrieved if you only know the pointer, p.
>   There are two popular techniques that do this. Both these techniques
>   are in use by commercial-grade compilers, both have tradeoffs, and
>   neither is perfect. These techniques are:
>
> 1. Over-allocate the array and put n just to the left of the first Fred object.
> 2. Use an associative array with p as the key and n as the value.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It works.

In fact, the only valid thing to do with a pointer obtained from `new[]` is to `delete[]` it.

The compiler will insert additional information into the memory that it obtains from the OS to allow it to keep track of how large the allocated blocks are. This information allows data that are only identified by a pointer to be correctly destructed and deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not and should not delete each element in turn. You get undefined results. When allocating memory the compiler includes housekeeping data.